# Set agents final destination to a polygon in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have a agent start within a polygon called winter and end in a polygon called summer. I got the agent to successfully start within the winter polygon but I'm struggling to set the final destination to a patch within the summer polygon. I keep getting this error for the destination-patch statement:

```
"WITH expected a true/false value from (patch 1 63), but got 0 instead.
error while observer running ONE-OF
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'"
```

Here's my code:

```
    extensions [ gis ]
    globals [
      elevation
      vegetation
      roads
      fence
      q
      max-energy
      dest-patch
      winter
      summer

    ]
    patches-own [
      used?
      pelev
      veg
      is-road?
      is-fence?
      veg-suitability
      resource
      elev-suitability
      is-winter?
      is-summer?
    ]

    turtles-own [
      start-patch
      target-patch
      energy

    ]

    to setup
      clear-all

      set max-energy 10
      set dest-patch one-of patches with [is-summer?] ; **this is where I get my error when I try to setup my model.

      set winter gis:load-dataset ("Lowuse_winter.shp")
      ;gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of winter
      ask patches [ set is-winter? false]
      ask patches gis:intersecting winter
      [ set is-winter? true]

      gis:set-drawing-color blue
      gis:draw winter 1

      set summer gis:load-dataset ("Lowuse_summer.shp")
      ;gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of summer

      ask patches [ set is-summer? false]
      ask patches gis:intersecting summer
      [ set is-summer? true]

      gis:set-drawing-color green
      gis:draw summer 1

      ;; set fence gis:load-dataset ("highfence_project.shp")
      ;gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of fence

     ;'ask patches [ set is-fence? false ]
      ;ask patches gis:intersecting fence
      ;[ set is-fence? true ]

      ;gis:set-drawing-color [255   0   0]
      ;gis:draw roads 1
      ;ask patches[
      ;  if is-fence? = true [set pcolor red]
      ;]


      crt 15
      [
        set size 4
        set energy random (deer-gain-from-food)
        set start-patch patch-here
        set color yellow
    ;    set xcor -17
    ;    set ycor -17
        move-to one-of patches with [is-winter?]
        pen-down
      ]
      reset-ticks
    end


to go
  ask turtles [
    if patch-here = dest-patch [stop]
    ifelse energy < deer-gain-from-food / 10 ;; If only 10% of energy
    [
      ifelse [resource] of patch-here > 0 ;; Is there anything to eat
      [; If there is - eat it and restore energy
        forage
      ]
      [ ; If not - mvoe to a neighboring patch with resources
        forage-move
      ]
    ]
    [
      migrate-move
    ]
    set energy energy - 1
  ]

    paint-resource

    tick
end

to forage
  set energy energy + deer-gain-from-food
  ask patch-here [
;    set resource resource - 0.1
    set resource 0
  ]
end

to forage-move
  set target-patch max-one-of neighbors with [ veg-suitability > 0] [ resource ]
  move-to target-patch ; error for "move-to expected input but got nobody instead"
  set used? TRUE
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you received, that "WITH expected a true/false value from (patch 1 63), but got 0 instead." was due to the fact that `is-summer?` was initialized by `clear-all` to `0`, so

```
set dest-patch one-of patches with [is-summer?]
```

gives the `with` operator the number zero rather than a true/false value. This line of code should go later in the setup procedure, **after** the patches have set their `is-summer?` variable to either `true` or `false`, perhaps just before the line

```
;; set fence gis:load-dataset ("highfence_project.shp")
```

Note that ZINAN10's answer does eliminate the error message, but placed where it is now, it is equivalent to saying

```
set dest-patch one-of patches with [0 = true]
```

which, of course is never true. `dest-patch` will be `nobody`.  In general, if a variable truly has a true/false value, you should not use the `=` operator as it will hide precisely the kind of error you have encountered here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Charles, this makes sense because I've been getting a nobody error when I tried to run the model. After moving the set destination patch to where you recommended, it now works. Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon. Every other time I run this model I encounter the error "MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead. Any thoughts?

Comment: The only place that I see `move-to` is in the line `move-to one-of patches with [is-winter?]`.  Presumably there are no such patches. Why don't you put just before the move-to line `if not any? patches with [is-winter?] [show "no winter patches!"]` to see if that is so. Then, the question is why.  But is this happening in your `go` procedure? We don't have the code for that. And is it literally every other time, or just on and off?

Comment: I get the nobody error in the line move-to target-patch within the to forage-move statement when I click go in my interface. I posted the rest of my code above. It's on and off, not literally every other time.

Comment: if you are getting that error in the line `set target-patch max-one-of neighbors with [ veg-suitability > 0] [ resource ]`, then there is no neighbor with `veg-suitability > 0`.  And indeed, in the code you have provided, I don't see where `veg-suitability` is set at all.  Like all variables, it is initialized to zero, but unless it is being set to a non-zero value in your calls to the gis extension, you will get that error every time `forage-move` is executed. You can test that with `if not any? patches with [veg-suitability > 0]  [show "no neighbor"]` as the first line in the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by final destination but from what I can see, I think maybe you should have a true or false here.

```
set dest-patch one-of patches with [is-summer? true/false]
```

Try that or make clearer where your error is.

Edit, yeah, try adding a true or false there , right now its empty .

Comment: I want the destination patch for the agent to be any patch within the summer polygon. I get the " with true/false error" when I try to set up my model. I starred it in my code where I'm getting the error. I tried what you mentioned above but no luck.  set dest-patch one-of patches with [is-summer? [true]]. Netlogo won't accept this for some reason. It says there are bracket errors.I also tried it without brackets but it asks for brackets.

Comment: try set dest-patch one-of patches with [is-summer? =  true]

Oops forgot to add the equal too sign, now try what I copied.

Comment: Just tried that. It says 'Expected closing bracket'

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it